# Unity - GameObject.Find() works only on server

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am making a simple networking game. The scene has a button named 'ReloadButton' and i am trying to find this button and add a listener to it through my script attached on the player.

```
    private Button reloadBtn;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject tempGO = GameObject.Find("ReloadButton");

        if (tempGO != null)
        {
            reloadBtn = tempGO.GetComponent<Button>();
            reloadBtn.onClick.AddListener(weaponManager.Reload);
        }
    }
```

I am doing it this way because direct referencing of 'ReloadButton' to the script through public `Button`variable is not possible.

The code works fine on the server, the listener is also added correctly. but on the client, the `GameObject.Find("ReloadButton")` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Seems like the client cannot find the Button itself.
I cannot proceed further in my project without solving this problem, I hope some of you can point me towards the problem.

Comment: Is the button in the scene before you start the game, or are you instantiating it?

Comment: @Hristo It is already in the scene.

Comment: And when you launch the client, is the button present in the hierarchy and is it active and enabled?

Comment: GameObject.Find wont throw a NullReferenceException if it can't find it. Does the script inherit from MonoBehaviour? Does it exist on an object in the scene?

Comment: Heres the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

Comment: @Fredrik its not the `GameObject.Find` that is throwing the exception. its the fact that he wants to access it afterwords (`tempGO.GetComponent<Button>();`)

Comment: @Fredrik.. Thank you for your replies, I am doing some other functionality in the update function. Maybe that is the problem. Here is the update function.    `if (currentWeapon.bullets < currentWeapon.maxBullets)
                    reloadBtn.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            else
                    reloadBtn.gameObject.SetActive(false);` @Hristo

Comment: It sounds weird that `tempGO.GetComponent<Button>();` would be null when you're doing `tempGO != null` just before. Are you sure it's not the `reloadBtn.onClick` that is null, meaning there is no Button Component on tempGO, therefore `GetComponent<Button>()` is null.?

Comment: If that was the case then it shouldn't have worked on the Server as well, but it works fine on the server. @Fredrik

Comment: share the error with line number of error

Comment: @Fredrik @Hristo @Mohammad Faizan Khan  I solved it, In the update method, `reloadBtn.gameObject.setActive(false)` this line was disabling the component from server for all the clients, So before `if` condition i just added `if(isLocalPlayer)`. Now the button gets disabled only on local clients and everything works just fine. Thank you for the help :)